# Simplify Room Owner moderatorship and allow consistency

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation, room-owner

I haven't been a Room Owner all that long, but I am already beginning to miss some features that would enable me to allow for more consistent moderation of rooms I am involved in.

As Room Owner of 2 Rooms I'm missing the ability to gather information on previous behaviour of users in the room I am moderating. When a user misbehaves I prefer to warn them (depending on the "severity") multiple times. If a certain threshold of warnings (totally subjective btw.) is reached, I take action.

For me it is hard to have an overview of how many warnings a user has recieved in the past, whether that be from me or from other room owners. It would enable me to consistently and transparently moderate if I knew the relevant things from possibly huge transcript in my absent periods (yes I do sleep sometimes).

As such I'd  love to be able to leave notes on a user (or somewhere else for general problems) for other room owners and moderators to see.
These notes should be at least room-specific and not visible to normal chat-users.

The content of notes would be at the discretion of Room Owners.

What do you think of this idea?

Comment: You're not the first to discover that chat moderation sucks. Things got better when kick-mute was added. But it's like a cup of water on a forest fire.

Comment: Two things that seem relevant: (1) ownership is sometimes assigned by the system automatically, and (2) room owners have not signed the moderation agreement.

Comment: @MonicaCellio ad 1) Automatically assigned ownership exists only in newly created chatroom (AFAIR). ad 2) yes. The implications are not quite clear to me though. The information contained there can only be what room owners can find out anyways, it's just making that information easily accessible (at least that is the idea). I am not proposing to make the moderator notes accessible to Room Owners, but a whole different set of notes.

Comment: On (1) actually no; I just saw this happen in an old room a week or so ago (last owner was manually removed without being replaced, and a day or two later the room auto-assigned a new owner).  On (2), this needn't be a barrier or anything; it's just an extra consideration, e.g. they probably can't just expose certain already-existing info now so some tweaks would be needed.  I commented so that answers could take these things into account; I'm not knocking the proposal.

Comment: As an alternative, if someone is raising such behaviour that you find objectionable, and you wish to see action taken, you could raise a custom moderator flag.

Answer (score 10):

Annotations for chat users already exist, but they are only visible to diamond moderators.

Room owners are pretty much selected at random. Anyone that has access to private user history should at least have accepted the moderator agreement, I don't think we should just give out that information to anyone that becomes room owner.

It actually might make sense to give room owners more moderator powers, but that can't happen unless there is a better process to determine who gets to be room owner.

Comment: I did not propose to make these moderator notes visible to room owners, but create a separate possibility for room owners to add such notes. But I also see your point about the necessity to make room ownership more binding by establishing some process.

Comment: [Not *all* room owners are selected at random.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/should-mos-eisley-have-non-moderator-owners-and-if-so-who).  I think the process Mos Eisley used to pick ROs was more or less identical to how mods are elected - Meta question, vote, (behind the scenes) CM approval.  Might be a good idea for all primary chat rooms.

Comment: Yeah, if the objection to letting the cops write tickets, or have tasters, is that we don't know their qualifications, then maybe the solution is to stop handing out police badges to unqualified people

Comment: ^^^That should be "tasers", not "tas**t**ers". Stupid autocorrect.

Answer (score 5):

I like the idea of transparency very much. I don't think annotations are a good way to introduce this as much for Room Owners.

I would rather just have more access for Room Owners to see deleted content in their room.

**Allow Room Owners to see the history of flagged messages in their room**.

Comment: Hmm... Just a quick note, I don't even think diamond moderators can see flag history in rooms. If we can, well... I haven't found it.

Comment: @Zizouz212 - I know you can see deleted messages in the transcript, which obviously is different, but even those are not centralized. I think there is definitely a need for this type of information to be available in one place.

Comment: Yep, in total agreement :)